# Firefox 60.3.0 ESR on Debian 9.5 AMD64 zooming bug?

Tags: firefox, debian, browser, zoom

#### Purpose

I need standard zooming functionality to work properly on Firefox 60.3 ESR.

#### Problem description

I run Firefox 60.3 ESR. Preferences are default, about:config is default. No extensions in the browser, neither meta-extensions in Debian.

I open a website. I use touchpad to access the "hamburger" menu in Firefox and single click zoom in. Zoom in goes straight to 67% from 100%. When I click zoom out, zoom level goes to 80%, but not higher.

#### Questions

Is this a bug?
How do I restore proper zoom functionality, e.g. zooming down in single steps and zooming out to a 100+% ?
What is the method/approach how to proceed to find the cause of this problem?

Comment: You can install the newest release of Firefox, and test if the problem persists. You can install an older version and see, if the problem is a regression.